# Mysql creating a top 10

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have big database full of information and I use the following Query to select the information I need.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16GB%'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

This leaves me with about 250 results, I use a while loop and display a [tr] for each result. Now I want to create a top ten. This is what I came up with:

```
$monthavg = ($row['price_shipping'] / $row['abo_time']) + ($row['price'] / $row['abo_time']) + $row['abo_price'];
```

So now I can echo $monthavg and its a good way to get a top ten. What I would rather like to do is just show 10 rows [tr] with the lowest $monthavg. But I already echo'd a table to the screen.

My question: Can I create a top 10 of my database and echo just those 10 results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the answer, just redo the query with your calculation as column, then order by that column and limit it to first 10 results

```
SELECT *, (price_shipping / abo_time + price / abo_time + abo_price) AS month_avg 
FROM db WHERE model LIKE '%iphone 4%' AND model LIKE '%16GB%'
ORDER BY month_avg ASC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know I could do it like this :-)